# Logging user out on time expiry

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, cookies

I'm working on a nodejs(express) server and a react FE utilising API's. The server token stores a token and secret. The secret gets refreshed when the user logs out of FE. (the original developer used custom authentication and not JWT..)
The problem is, if the user does not press the logout button, they can be logged in indefinitely. In terms of a solution I've had an ideas where somehow the server can monitor the last request from the client, when 30mins have lapsed, the server can update the secret- I tried this manually and when the client was refreshed the api call failed ungracefully. I could build in some extra logic in the FE, catching the error displaying to the user a logout message and then deleting the local storage.
In addition, the client could count 25 mins from the last api call, and display dialog with a countdown before logging out the user.

Perhaps, I'm over complicating this and there is another way - Currently using local storage but unsure if I was to use cookies, it would solve the problem of auto logout on browser inactivity or browser closing and also if it's possible to have a dialog countdown before a cookie expires (which gets renewed should the user select keep session open)

Would be grateful on a workable option.

Code:

```
api/createCustomer

schemaObj.customerToken = crypto.createHash('sha1').update(uuidv4()).update(config.hidden.salt).digest('hex');
schemaObj.customerSecret = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(uuidv4()).update(config.hidden.secret).digest('hex');
schemaObj.password = bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(10));


api/login

var loginValid = bcrypt.compareSync(password, bidder.password);
....
res.apiSuccess(customer);
```

react code:

```
axios.post('/api/login', formData)
let { customerToken, customerSecret, isVerified } = res.data.data;
.....

localStorage.setItem("customerData", JSON.stringify({ customerToken, customerSecret }));
```

Comment: JWT or any other key, should not be stored in local storage because of XSS attack.Can you eloborate on how this custom token system works? Is it a session or a bear token or some json like jwt (that's has expire property)

Comment: Wasn't sure how to answer your question, can you tell from the server code I've added to the post? -

Comment: Yeah helps a little. What's the difference between customerToken and customerSecret?

Comment: customerToken is the customer Id and customerSecret acts as a password. Both these get sent to the FE. When an api is called from the FE, these both customerToken  customerSecret are passed back to the server and authenticated. When the customer logs out manually, the customerSecret is refreshed,

Comment: Any ideas what type of authentication has been employed? and how I can meet my requirements?

Comment: After the secret has been set to local storage is it then sent with all other requests from the react code? Is there a code that authorizes the secret? The code that checks if the secret is valid should somehow check if it's expired or not.

Comment: When the secret is received by react, it is stored in local storage. The secret is sent back to the server for all secure api calls.
The sever checks the incoming secret and compares it to the stored version, If a match occurs, it allows processing. There is no check for expiry. When the token is generated in the first place on the server, no expiry is recorded anywhere.

Comment: on the secure api's middleware exists that authenticates the secret,
CustomerRoute.post('/updatePassword', customerAuth, (req, res) => {....}

Comment: Thank you. Can we see this code: "The sever checks the incoming secret and compares it to the stored version, If a match occurs, it allows processing.". Where is the stored version of the secret? In a database?

Comment: When the secret is created it is stored in the db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want expiration on login you have to save a timestamp property somewhere to check against it. Most standard authentication system have this in place, e.g. JWT has exp claim and cookies have max-age.

For custom system like the one you have described you need to keep track of this yourself.

As I understand the system

- customerToken = id of the customer
- customerPassword = password to log in
- customerSecret = the actual token that is sent with all request from react to the server.

So the server recieves the customerSecret, it has a middlewere that checks that secret against the database to check if the user should be allowed to continue or not.

You have few of options

### Add column logintime to your usertable.

- When user logs in then update that field with current timestamp.
- When the secret is looked up in the database check if the timestamp from login is within 30 minutes.

### Use cookies

- When user logs in add the secret to a cookie.
- use withCredentials in react application to send the cookie to the server
- In the middlewere check the cookie instead of looking into the database

### Move the secret to redis

- When user logs in, add secret to redis with expire property.
- Send the secret from react as Bearer
- In the middelewere look up the secret in redis to check the user.

### Few pointers overall in authentication and authorization:

- Reading a full transactional database on every request is expensive.
- Session state is data-loss tolerant, it doesn't matter if it gets lost, you can always recreate/restore it.
- You should never store secrets or tokens in localStorage, since its on the client and hence accessible by other applications.

Comment: Thank-you. Choosing option 'use Cookies' or 'Move the secret to redis' - does it mean I no longer need to store secret in DB? In both options as, secret and expiry is being sent to the FE, when cookie about to expire, could I launch a script on FE to prompt the user to renew cookie (refreshing the cookie could then restart the client timer) ?

Comment: Yes, you wouldn't need to store the secret in the database. Yes you could could check the expiration on the cookie and or redis when there's a request from FE and if its maybe 5 min or less you update it again to 30 min.

Comment: Hi, If I use cookies, when returned to server, i can return customerToken and customerSecret - Then server will need to check both of these against either Redis or DB. If found, then check stored expiry. If expiry near end then renew. I think I don't need customerToken to go back and forth (as its always the same), but the customerSecret is required to go to FE and BE, as it gets refreshed every so often. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like

```
setTimeout(function(){ req.session.destroy(); }, milliseconds_since_page_loaded);
```

or use req.session.destroy(); where ever it best fits. I'm not sure I fully understood when you wanted to timeout.

Maybe you can have a variable set as time since last call and then every minute give it ++, then add to any of your functions that perform a call to reset it, and every 30 minutes/however long it checks that variable.

Comment: Ideally, I want to timeout 30minutes after the user stops interacting with the Front-end. Is the code you mentioned server side ?

Comment: It is server side.